# Play YouTube video in MFC

Tags: c++, mfc, video-streaming

I am using C++ with MFC. I wonder if there is any way to play a youtube video on a control in MFC. Ideally, I just have the share link I get from the Youtube website and send the link to the control and it will play the video. It doesn't really matter if there is no advanced functionality, I just want to play it.

Is there any controls for this?

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The easiest would undoubtedly be to use a web-browser control. Pass the URL to its Navigate2 member function, and you're on your way.

Edit: I should probably also mention that if this is the primary point of the application, so you'll be doing it in a normal view window, you can simplify things a bit by deriving that view window from CHtmlView.

Answer (score 1):

Insert Activex control WebBrowser Control on your dialog. 
Use navigate() method to navigate it to your youtube url. It uses IE's instance to render web pages.